# Cannot install Checkstyle plugin on Eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle, sevntu-checkstyle

I tried to install Checkstyle plugin on Eclipse Mars, both via Eclipse Marketplace and via the update site (http://eclipse-cs.sf.net/update).
I set the option to contact other updates sites to satisfy dependencies, but I got following error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Extension for eclipse-cs
>   plugin with additional Checks 1.13.5
>   (com.github.sevntu.checkstyle.checks.feature.feature.group 1.13.5)
>   Missing requirement: Sevntu eclipse-cs Extension Plugin 1.13.5
>   (eclipsecs-sevntu-plugin 1.13.5) requires 'bundle
>   net.sf.eclipsecs.checkstyle 0.0.0' but it could not be found   Cannot
>   satisfy dependency:
>       From: Extension for eclipse-cs plugin with additional Checks 1.13.5 (com.github.sevntu.checkstyle.checks.feature.feature.group 1.13.5)
>       To: eclipsecs-sevntu-plugin [1.13.5]

UPDATE:
I installed the plugin from the archive successfully, but online install doesn't work.

Comment: I had to install from the downloaded archive as well.

Answer (score 2):

The link http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/#!/install gives four different approaches to install the CheckStyle plugin on Eclipse:

1. Via Eclipse Marketplace link (recommended)
2. Via Eclipse Marketplace client
3. From the update site
4. From an update site archive

The first approach (dragging and dropping the link to the workspace) performs an online install, and worked fine for me with Eclipse Mars.

The second option (Via Eclipse Marketplace client) did not work. I got this error: "The following solutions are not available: CheckStyle Contributions (id=de.unkrig.cs-contrib.feature.feature.group, site=http://cs-contrib.unkrig.de/update)"

Comment: The same happened to me. Looks like there is some misleading dependency metadata in all choices but first.